# Regular post/answer is showing as "Community-wiki Answer"

Tags: support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

I have posted an answer to the question: *"Which programming languages can be used to develop in Android?"*

The answer is here: [Which programming languages can be used to develop in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316801/which-programming-languages-can-be-used-to-develop-in-android/3316970#3316970)

As it is a *regular* post, I have also got +195 points for the 18 upvotes and 15 for accepted answer, but now it is showing as "Community wiki".

What's the reason behind that? Any rule?

Comment: No wonder many highly voted answers are cw on stackoverflow. I always had thought some users here really dont care about rep and they just graciously and willingly make it cw.. Now I know its not :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 12th edit made it so automatically, see the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3316970/revisions).

Note that [this feature has since been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940) and editing a question or an answer can no longer convert it to Community Wiki. For more information about Community Wiki posts, please see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: So why didn't it happen on the 8th edit? Is that info out of date or do some edits not count?

Comment: @Martin Smith: as the `* note` states, *the actual behavior of SO is subject to change without notice, and may well have done so since this was last updated...*

Comment: Yes I read that as well. I suppose either way the information is incomplete or out of date but if anyone can confirm that the limit is now 12 that would be useful to know.

Comment: @Martin: Edits in a short (five minute?) widow are treated as one by the system. That is, their edit comments are merged, they "editted <time> ago" bit shows only the first time from the clusters, and (I believe) they count as one edit for CW bookkeeping.

Comment: @Martin Smith Ya exactly...why didn't it happen on the 8th edit ??

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler you have told that "An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki." then check out my question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405695/importantuseful-websites-for-the-android-related-stuff/3405735#3405735 , here y didnt it marked as "Community wiki post"?????????

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: because you turned the question CW at 13:02 (see [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3405695/revisions)) but posted the answer at 13:00. When a question is turned CW, the answers remain unchanged unless a mod turns everything CW. You have to manually turn your answer into CW if you want.

Comment: @dmckee: those edits are not even kept track of, i.e. they won't show up as different revisions

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for the update!