# Answer is not shown as "Community wiki answer"

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

Hello,

As somebody answered me in my one of the question: [Regular Post-Answer is showing as "Community-wiki Answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60197/regular-post-answer-is-showing-as-community-wiki-answer/60198#60198)

I also know and he also answered that **"An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki."**

Then, Check out my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405695/importantuseful-websites-for-the-android-related-stuff/3405735#3405735
Here the question is as a "community wiki" and i have also given answer,...then why didnt it marked as "Community wiki" answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others said, it's because you posted the answer before the question became CW. You can use the [revisions view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3405695/revisions) to see when a post was made CW; you answered at 13:00 and it became CW at 13:02.

Comment: But now it is shown as "Community wiki", dont know whats happening?

Comment: @Paresh CW is short for Community Wiki. I'm not sure which part you're confused by; the definition of Community Wiki is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) if that helps

Answer (score 3):

If he answers before you make it a Community Wiki, it isn't marked CW.

Comment: But now it is shown as "Community wiki", dont know whats happening?

Comment: @Paresh The author can manually mark it as a CW. This is common in situations like your where a question turns CW and the answer doesn't. Usually the author will manually mark their answer as CW to fit in with the rest of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was given *before* the question was marked as Community Wiki. Only answers given *after* the question becomes Community Wiki are set as CW by default.